# Quando gravar logs em banco de dados?

Tags: log

Participo de uma equipe que está desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando Zend framework 2 e banco de dados MySQL. Precisamos desenvolver um recurso de gravação de logs das ações realizadas pelos usuários de modo a possibilitar auditorias pela própria aplicação. Somos uma equipe nova e essa é a primeira vez que vamos fazer algo assim. Tenho receio de gravar os logs em banco e a tabela ficar muito grande.

Então minha pergunta: **quando é indicado gravar logs no banco de dados?**

Comment: tres anos depois, e fica um comentário: logar no DB é prático, mas é uma camada a mais para dar problema. Se o dado é importante demais, faça o log o mais "primitivamente" possivel (log do sistema, arquivo) e transcreva no DB depois, assim se o DB falhar, não perdeu o registro original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a pergunta é um tanto quanto ampla e as respostas vão depender da experiência de cada um).

Se tiver oportunidade, faça os logs na BD:

- Torna mais fácil manipular os dados;
- É simples de limpar e gerir (backups automáticos et al);
- Tem durabilidade garantida pela BD;
- Pode aceder à BD por rede facilmente sem ter de partilhar pastas;

Nota:

No caso de ter uma aplicação que vai ficar do lado do cliente, ai diria que é preferível fazer o log de ambas as maneiras. Os logs gerais na BD mas ter logs em ficheiro também (para os niveis mais elevados (Warning, Error, Fatal)) de forma a que em caso de problemas, o cliente possa enviar os ficheiros sem ter de saber como usar a BD.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente a sua pergunta será fechada por ser baseada em opiniões, mas acredito que posso responder algo dentro do escopo do SO.

Tenhas receios sim, mas não pelo facto da tabela ficar grande e sim optimiza-la da melhor forma. Um bom exemplo de optimização é utilizar índices.

O problema não é ser grande, se fosse assim o facebook estaria em maus lençóis, e sim a performance da sua base de dados/aplicação.

Os logs não são consultados com frequência (na maioria dos casos) e sim eventualmente e fará bastante falta quando, por exemplo, algo não correr conforme previsto.

Se o seu medo é deixar o utilizador bloqueado ao gerar um log, faça isso em background na linguagem que você está usando e deixe o utilizador livre para continuar a usar a aplicação.

Comment: Eu complementaria essa resposta dizendo que você deve gravar tantos logs quantos forem necessários para satisfazer seu nível de paranóia por controle. Desenvolvedores maníacos registram TUDO, mas tudo mesmo: login, logou, cadastro, edição de perfil... Se você não precisar de tanto, registre nos pontos-chave. Usando o exemplo do @LeonardoPatrício, grave na exclusão de um item, na edição de um item (preço desconto...), no uso de um cupom de desconto na hora do checkout...

Comment: @BrunoAugusto isso já é uma opinião e tentei não levar para este lado.

Comment: Por isso que eu comentei ao invés de responder ;)